# How do I pass my API data to a React component? (Sandbox link included)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

If I am posting incorrectly, I apologize, but I've literally been at it for 9 hours, and I am ready to walk into traffic.

I forked the real-world React+Redux app found here:https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world

My fork is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkq867jwll

The real-world example loads data when the route changes. Instead of that, my fork loads data when you click the "Go!" button. Loading is fine, the data is normalized correctly, and it appears in `state.entities.artifacts` as expected.

My last remaining problem is that I cannot get the List component, which should display the items in `state.entities.artifacts` to display. It doesn't even attempt to re-render after I get search results back from the API.

Let me sprinkle in the fact that I am completely new to React and Redux, and I am literally banging my head on the desk with this.

**:(**

Comment: I see that you've solved your problem by properly connecting your redux state to your components. Please add an answer to your question explaining your solution for the benefit of future knowledge-seekers. :)

Comment: Thanks @jered for your help! I cannot accept my answer until tomorrow apparently, but I'll be sure to do so.

Comment: Also, I will likely open another ticket for setting up pagination. Any experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who's having the same problem, the answer was to map my items (`state.entities.artifacts`) to the props via `mapStateToProps`, like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  artifacts: state.entities.artifacts,
  ...
});
```

And then I can use it in components like this:

```
<List
  config={searchConfig}
  artifacts={artifacts}
  totalResults={totalResults}
/>
```

For a full example of how this works, you can see my sandbox at: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkq867jwll

Thanks!